# It is possible to prevent keyboard open when click on eye icon in ion-item?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying not to open the keyboard when we click on the icon in ion-item.

[image]

This is my login page view, in this, I have added an eye icon to show/hide the password.

the issue is when I am clicking on an icon, the keyboard is also opening. at this time I want to prevent the keyboard from opening.

For this tried this solution event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); but it didn't work.

```
  <ion-item lines="none" class="formfield">
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-icon class="first-icon" src="assets/icons/password.svg"></ion-icon>
    <ion-input [type]="passShow? 'text' : 'password'" class="font-weight-600"
               formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon class="second-icon" [src]="passShow? 'assets/icons/eye.svg' : 'assets/icons/eye-off.svg'"
              (click)="showPass()">
    </ion-icon>
  </ion-item>

  showPass() {
    this.passShow = !this.passShow;
  }
```

[image]
Please help me...

Comment: I have similar code but do not observe this behaviour. I would suspect this is a "fat finger" issue maybe.. both are getting the even. Try to add padding/marging. I use slot=end position, which add the marging by default.

Comment: Tried with the slot end and also tried with a new page in a new form item and input with slot end icon position but didn't work.